# Colorado Trespassing on Mechanic property

Tags: criminal-law, consumer-protection

Should you be liable for a trespassing ticket if you are watching a mechanic put your car back together? This would be due to not trusting a mechanic for multiple times of over charging fraud. (For a Friend.)

"If the dealer fails to notify the customer of a new completion date or the customer
refuses to consent, either party may cancel the repair order. If the contract is
cancelled, the dealer must reassemble the vehicle in substantially the same
condition in which it was delivered without cost to the customer. The customer is
required to pay for repairs already completed so long as the charge does not
exceed the original estimate or any subsequent estimate for repairs already
performed. 
Last Updated: 3/5/2008 4

The dealer does not have to reassemble the vehicle if the garage previously
informed the customer that such reassembly would be impractical."

http://www.cadaopenroad.org/enewsletter/enews_030508/MVRepairUpd2000-v3.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Tickets are for infractions like speeding or running a red light. Trespassing is a crime (cl. 1 petty offense); [third degree criminal trespass](http://codes.findlaw.com/co/title-18-criminal-code/co-rev-st-sect-18-4-504.html) most likely, if a "person unlawfully enters or remains in or upon premises of another". The severity of the crime increases depending on whether it is legally classified as agricultural land (presumably not but never make gratuitous assumptions about land use). The degree increases also if it is :premises of another which are enclosed in a manner designed to exclude intruders or are fenced". In order to watch the mechanic put the car back together, you would have to enter a non-public area, which likely has a sign of the "employees only" type, so you would have to get explicit permission. If they deny permission, then you would be entering or remaining unlawfully, and they might call the police (they can't legally hit you with a monkey wrench to get you to leave). So it really depends on whether you have permission. There is no provision in the law that allows you to override the property owner's right to exclude you, just because they are doing repair work.

Answer (score 0):

You would not be "liable" for trespass, and no one can legally issue you a ticket, however you may face prosecution - and if it comes to that, court fines.

If I were the mechanic and did not want you around, I would simply refuse to work on the car while you were around and call the cops to remove you if you refused to leave.  (The cop would most likely simply escort you from the premises)